# Stripe .NET 39.45 - Where did the Plan class association move to on the Subscription class?

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, .net-5

After upgrading from .Net Core 2.1 to .Net 5 (and subsequently upgrading my Stripe .net library to 39.45) I noticed some code of mine is now broken. I am specifically getting an error on the subscription object because it no longer has a "Plan" object on it. In my code below, I have my own internal table called 'Subscription' which actually contains a few more fields for convenience. Regardless, it looks like they moved the 'Plan' obj class from the Subscription class.

```
                var service = new SubscriptionService();
                var subscription = service.Get(successInvoice.SubscriptionId);

                if (subscription != null)
                {

                    var internalCustomer = _dbContext.Customers.First();
                    var internalSubscription = _dbContext.Subscriptions.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ExternalSubscriptionId == subscription.Id);

                    if (internalCustomer != null)
                    {
                        //If the subscription does not exist, it means this is the first time they are being charged
                        //and a new subscription must be added as well
                        if (internalSubscription == null)
                        {
                            internalSubscription = new Business.Entities.Billing.Subscription
                            {
                                CustomerId = internalCustomer.Id,
                                Customer = internalCustomer,
                                ExternalProductId = subscription.Plan.ProductId,
                                Amount = subscription.Plan.AmountDecimal.Value / 100,
                                Interval = subscription.Plan.Interval,
                                IntervalCount = subscription.Plan.IntervalCount,
                                ExternalSubscriptionId = subscription.Id
                            };

                            //Add this new subscription
                            _dbContext.Subscriptions.Add(internalSubscription);
                            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
                        }
```

So these lines of code are throwing the error:

```
                  ExternalProductId = subscription.Plan.ProductId,
                                Amount = subscription.Plan.AmountDecimal.Value / 100,
                                Interval = subscription.Plan.Interval,
                                IntervalCount = subscription.Plan.IntervalCount,
```

Does anyone know where they moved Plan to, or specifically how I can retrieve a Plan if I have a subscription? The purpose of this code is that I want to make my own

Answer (score 0):

`Plan` was removed from `Subscription` as [part of 39.1.2](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#3912---2020-09-01).

You now will need to do it [like this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/retrieve?lang=dotnet):

```
var service = new PlanService();
service.Get("price_1IjsKp2eZvKYlo2C4nz7QGls");
```

Comment: Ah interesting, thanks. Now remind me again, where do I get the price (string Id you passed into the function) from? This code resides in my webhook for if (stripeEvent.Type == "invoice.payment_succeeded"). Thank you for taking the time out to help!

Comment: You can use the `plan_` ID in its place.